# How simulate TLS handshake error. java, android,

Tags: java, android, ssl, server, handshake

My task is to simulate a TLS handshake error related to the fact that a website does not have an XYZ certificate.
I need to do this on an android device using a postman style app. Can anyone advise how to do something like this? how to cause such an error

I try to connect to https web site and receive error TLS

Comment: Your question could use more detail and focus. If I understand correctly, just configure a web server with a certificate that has the desired problem. There are many tools you can use depending on platform, e.g. Apache, IIS, nginx, or even more simply just use the `openssl s_server` command line tool. Or you can write a small program in e.g. Java, python, go, etc. to do this. It doesn't need to support the HTTP protocol because your scenario never gets past the TLS handshake.

Comment: What is an XYZ  certificate?

Comment: Do you know https://badssl.com? A lot of misconfigured web servers you can connect to and test app behavior.